Php Ftp File Transfer Failure writing to local file
Hi i using php  language to transfer the csv file without creating to local using ftp method. i have the following code to send the csv file without creating local directory but it throws error ftp_fput(): Failure writing to local file and ftp_fput(): Failed to establish connection guide me to clear the issue. some times file got transferred but the file is 0 bytes data.
$Gs_Str="Time,name,value1,value2\n"; 
$Gs_Str=$Gs_Str."$STime,$Name,$val1,$val2";

function ftp_file_put_contents($remote_file, $file_string) 
   {
    $ftp_server="data.gen.com"; 
    $ftp_user_name="kar"; 
    $ftp_user_pass="passw";

    $local_file=fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    fwrite($local_file, $file_string);
    rewind($local_file);       
    $ftp_conn=ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
    @$login_result=ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
   if($login_result) $upload_result=ftp_fput($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

   if(!$login_result or !$upload_result)
     {
       echo('<p>FTP error: The file could not be written to the FTP server.</p>');
     }
   ftp_close($ftp_conn);
   fclose($local_file);
  }

 ftp_file_put_contents("/VERUPL/15 Min/$STime.csv",$Gs_Str); 


1st quick question: So is it true that the /VERUPL/15 Min/ already exists and is write-permitted ?

Spaces in paths are an obvious potential issue right?  Have you tried using a directory name without a space?  What is $STime?

/VERUPL/15 Min/  it is available manually i check with winscp login

It is a path so it may contains space no issue in that

See PHP ftp_put fails. + If it does not help, please make the code easier to read for us (proper indentation, no unnecessary functions, etc).

Try ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true); after ftp_login function.

Is this a problem with CSV or with PHP? Would this work different when writing any other file?

@Don'tPanic Spaces shouldn't be a problem when accessing files from a program. They're a potential problem in shell commands, but proper quoting should solve it.
